# jqGrid: Error: Invalid XML

Tags: xml, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid filled with a custom XML response from the server. I managed to run it with datatype: "xmlstring", when the XML string is hard-coded locally, I also managed to run it when I get the XML from the response from jqXHR.responseText, and pass it as an XML string, still using datatype: "xmlstring", but when I set datatype: "xml", I get the following error:

An error occured during your request: Error: Invalid XML:

and after the error there is listed the code of the HTML page which does all of that, instead of the XML response, which seems odd to me.

The error happens when I set data: data, or data: jqXHR.responseText, or even data: jqXHR.responseXML.

Any ideas on this one? When using datatype: "xml", what should be the correct thing I should pass for jqGrid data - data, jqXHR.responseText, jqXHR.responseXML or some member of data?

Also what would be the benefit of using datatype: "xml", over datatype: "xmlstring"? If I don't manage to run it with datatype: "xml", could I use datatype: "xmlstring" with the XML coming from the response, and would there be any issue with that approach?

P.S. Versions: jqGrid v. 4.7.0, jQuery v. 2.1.3, Firefox v. 39.0 and IE 11.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

        var columnNames                 = [  "User ID", "Organization", "Email" ];
        var columnModels                = [
                { name: "userId", visibility: "mandatory", index: "userId", width: 100, xmlmap: '>Reference[name="LogicalMember"]>Object[type="LogicalMember"]>Attribute[name="login"]'},
                { name: "organization", index: "organization", xmlmap:'>Reference[name="Organization"]>Object[type="Organization"]>Attribute[name="name"]' },
                { name: "email", index: "email", width: 80, xmlmap:'>Reference[name="EmailAddresses"]>Object[type="EmailAddress"]>Attribute[name="address"]'},
            ];

            var filterModel                 = [
                { id: 'userId', name: 'User Id', renderer: 'text' },
                { id: 'organization', name: 'Organization', renderer: 'text', rendererOptions: { prompt: 'Domain*' } }
            ];

            var xmlMapping = {root:"SearchResponse", 
                              row:'SearchResponse>Object[type="Contact"]',
                              records:"SearchResponse[total-found]",
                              repeatitems:false,
                              id : "[id]"} 


            // PAGE INITIALIZATION
            //------------------------------------------------------------------
            $(document).ready( function() {
                var searchRequest = createUserSearchRequest('', '', '', '', null, '', '', 50, 1);
                var userSessionID = sessionStorage.getItem("UserSessionID");

                $.ajax({
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType : "xml",
                    url : "../../../../api/",
                    headers: {
                        "UserSessionID": userSessionID,
                        "include_extended_attributes" : false,
                        "ClientVersion" : "3.0",
                        "ClientApplication" : "SomeApp",
                        "Content-type" : "text/xml"
                    },
                    data : searchRequest
                })
                .done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {

                    var xml = jqXHR.responseText;

                    // Table ----------------------
                    var table = $("#table");
                    table.jqGrid(
                        {
                            data : data,
                            datatype:                   "xml",
                            colNames:                   columnNames,
                            colModel:                   columnModels,
                            multiselect:                true,
                            fixedLoadingDiv:            true, 
                            onSelectRow:                selectRow,
                            onSelectAll:                selectAllRow,
                            columnChooserButtonVisible: true,

                            // Sort config
                            cmTemplate:                 { sortable: true },
                            sortname:                   "userId",
                            sortorder:                  "desc",
                            onSortCol:                  applySort,


                            xmlReader: xmlMapping,

                            emptyrecords:               false,
                            columnsStateContextKey:     "some.context",
                            fixedTableHeader:           true
                        });
                    table.jqGrid('hideLoadingBar');
                })
                .fail(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    alert("Server error!");
                });

            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="grid-content">
            <table id="table"></table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing which I would recommend you to do is verifying whether you correctly includes jQuery and jqGrid on the page. You should modify the text of your question and include the version information about jQuery and jqGrid which you use. It could be important to know which web browser and in which version you use for your tests.

The next thing which I would recommend you to do is using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or Developer Tools of IE/Chrome/Firefox to trace the HTTP traffic between the server and the client. You should examine **the exact** body and headers of the server response. You should include the information in the text of your question. The most important is: which value have `Content-Type` header.

One more thing: you should start your HTML page in debugger (press <kbd>F12</kbd> to start Developer Tools and start script debugging). You will see the exact place where the error "Invalid XML" take place. You can see the call stack and do to the line of jQuery or jqGrid which was executed. It's much better if you would use non-minimized version of jQuery and jqGrid for all your tests.

**UPDATED**: The code fragment which you posted shows that you use jqGrid in th wrong way. First of all you misunderstand the meaning of `datatype` parameter.

The options `datatype: "xml"` or `datatype: "json"` should be used in combination with `url` parameter. `datatype: "xml"` without `loadonce: true` means that you implemented server side paging of data and jqGrid should send to `url` requests to load every page of data. You don't specified any `rowNum` option, so the default value `20` will be used. During creating of jqGrid it makes request to fill the grid to `url`. If no URL is specified then the request to the current page will be probably made.

The parameter `data` will be used by jqGrid only if you use `datatype: "local"`. The value of `data` parameter should be array with elements which represents the rows of the grid.

So if you want to load XML data from URL then you have to use `mtype: "POST", url: "../../../../api/", datatype: "xml", loadonce: true`. If you want to make request to URL separately then you should use `datatype: "xml", datastr: data`. The `data` can be pared XML object or the string with XML data.

If you don't load the data from static XML file I would recommend you to use JSON instead of XML. It's more quickly for both client side and the server side.

**UPDATE 2:** You can use the following options for example

```js
datatype: "xml",
url : "../../../../api/",
loadonce: true,
mtype: "POST",
postData: searchRequest,
ajaxGridOptions: {
    contentType: "text/xml",
    headers: {
        UserSessionID: userSessionID,
        include_extended_attributes: false,
        ClientVersion: "3.0",
        ClientApplication : "SomeApp"
    }
}
```

Comment: Oleg, yhank you for the reply! I am not 100% about the libraries versions, since they have been chosen by another people, but at least as per their documentation they should be: jqGrid v. 4.7.0, jQuery v. 2.1.3. I observe this in Firefox v. 39.0 and IE 11.

I forgot to mention that the error message appears in an alert box, so I am not sure whether I could use the debugger in that case?

Comment: Also, as per your recommendation I inspected the response headers, and there is no Content-Type header in the response - there is a single header, called "Transfer-Encoding" with a value "chunked". Maybe actually this is the issue?

Comment: @krisbg: Which tool you used for HTTP trace (Fiddler or some another one)? If you see "Transfer-Encoding" in the response that you need make one click more to decode the body. The headers are not encoded, so you can examine the value of `Content-Type:` header directly. The version of jqGrid you can see in JS file in the first comments of the file (`jquery.jqGrid.js` or `jquery.jqgrid.src.js`). **Do you debugged the code**? You can search for `$.ajax` and set breakpoints on [the line](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L2059) or on the first line inside of `error`

Comment: The versions inside the files are as already written above. I use Firebug to inspect the response. There is NO Content-Type: header in the response - maybe this is the cause for the issue? I am going to debug the jQuery code now for some ideas why the error occurs.

Comment: The `Content-Type` exists typically (at least `Content-Type 
text/plain`), but in case of wrong value jQuery can interpret the response **not** as XML data. `application/json` is the mostly correct value for JSON and `application/xml` for XML data. The `text/xml` value is also OK, but will be interpreted in a little another way as `application/xml`. Nevertheless it's important to know **who throw the error**. Do you debugged the code? Which component (jQuery, jqGrid) reports `Invalid XML` error? Is the XML response really correct? Has it `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` line?

Comment: @krisbg: You should **append** the text of your question with the information from Firebug (HTTP headers and the body with XML data, at least the beginning ...).

Comment: Just debugged it, and the issue happens in jquery.js in the function:

 jQuery.parseXML = function( data )

The strange thing here is that this function is executed two times. The first time the data parameter contains the actual XML response from the server, and there is no issue with parsing it, but the second time the data parameter contains the code of my HTML page, and by no surprise, I get the error. The question is now why parseXML is called for the second time. I didn't write this code from scratch, so I am going to look around what could be causing the second call.

Comment: Unfortunately at least in IE the call stack doesn't show so many levels, to the initial place, so I can't tell where does this come from, and also I have some issues with debugging in Firefox - Firebug debugger just hangs forever when it has to stop on a breakpoint. Maybe I should try Chrome as well.

Comment: OK. At least one knows now that the reason is the second call of `jQuery.parseXML`. You should use any debugger which you knows (IE/Chrome/Firebug etc) to locale in the call stack the places of the both calls of `jQuery.parseXML`. It will shows you the reason of the issue.

Comment: Unfortunately with both IE and Firefox I can't debug as far back as needed. With IE I can go one step further back up to jQuery.ajaxTransport() inside jquery.js, which seems to be called twice. I can't test with Chrome currently for some other reasons.

Comment: What happens though is: in the Net tab of Firebug I see first my HTML page loaded with a GET request with no request parameters in the URL, then some GET requests for all JavaScript includes, then my XML POST request, then again several other GET requests which load only some images, and at the very end I have a GET request which loads again my main HTML page, but at the end of the request URL now I have some parameters, which seem to be jqGrid sorting and pagination options.

Comment: I can't figure out where this second GET comes from, but in the Console tab I see only my XML POST request and this second GET request for my HTML page. I am wondering could this be connected with the place I execute the AJAX call and fire the jqGrid function? Currently I fire the AJAX request inside $(document).ready(), and in the done callback I fire the jqGrid function.

Comment: Could it be that the XML response is returned before the whole HTML page is loaded, and some confusion to arise from that, because with the XML POST request I change the Content-Type to text/xml before the HTML page has been fully loaded?

Comment: @krisbg: I use Developer Tools of IE permanently for debugging. You can click on "Call stack" and then choose any level on the stack by click. You can see the exact place of the code on any level and all local variables on the level. About your last comments: **I should see the HTML page with JavaScript code which creates jqGrid to say more**. Do you load XML data from static file or your server generates the response from the database dynamically?

Comment: After some more debugging this time with IE, I narrowed down the cause of the issue. Please note, that I added a code snippet in my initial post. It is not the complete code on my side, but is enough to show what happens. So, the offending GET request is called when I call table.jqGrid() in the example above. This makes me think that I am doing it all wrong, and maybe I should not fire the POST request with my own call, but pass it to jqGrid to make the POST request? If the latter is the case, I have some new questions:

Comment: - How to set the jgGrid POST request body (I want to put custom XML there)?
- How to set the jqGrid request headers?  Use loadBeforeSend event handler or some other method?

Comment: @krisbg: see **UPDATED** part of my answer.

Comment: Oleg, thank you for the reply! My response is created dynamically by the server, but I cannot make changes on the server side, so XML is the only option. What is more important though is that I have to send an XML request as well - the request body should contain XML which directs the server on result filtering, so I need to understand how to pass that XML to the AJAX call if I want to use the request made inside the jgGrid() function, without making a separate call? I guess I also need a way to exclude the search options from the url in that case?

Comment: @krisbg: All the question are about **the server side**. The solution depends on the language which you use on the server side, from the framework and many many other details.

Comment: Please excuse me, but I am unable to understand how the solution depends on the language on the server side? If I use two requests, with datatype set to "xmstring", it works perfectly. I just wanted to know if this is the best way, and whether I could use only one request with datatype set probably to "xml". Is there a way to pass my custom XML request to jqGrid, so it could send it via the AJAX call?

Comment: @krisbg: I'm not sure what you ask. The code which you posed can't work because you used `datatype: "xml", data: data`. If the values like `datatype: "xmlstring", datastr: data` for example works correctly then you can remove outer Ajax call and use the following options: `datatype: "xml", url : "../../../../api/", loadonce: true, mtype: "POST", postData: searchRequest, ajaxGridOptions: {contentType: "text/xml", headers: {UserSessionID: userSessionID, include_extended_attributes: false, ClientVersion: "3.0", ClientApplication : "SomeApp" }}`

Comment: Oleg, thank you, this is what I needed and it works just fine! I apologize for the late reply!